# Events not appearing in angular ui calendar

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I'm using Angular ui calendar in my app.
Everything is working fine. The calendar is showing, but events are not appearing in the calendar.
Here is my code: -

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.events = [
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2019-01-10'
        }
      ];
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
    return $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar: {
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'today prev,next'
         }
      }
    };
   },5000);
```

Here I'm using timeout because I want some delay for calendar to be loaded.
This is my HTML code: -

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="span8 calendar" ng-model="events" calendar="myCalendar" style="height:700px;"></div>
```

The docs suggest you should give an array named eventSources. I have given it, but nothing works.
Please suggest what I'm doing wrong.
Here is the screenshot: -

[image]

Comment: Can you create snippet to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing scope variables after sometime 5 seconds, your calendar is getting the `undefined` variables and hence if you check your console there are errors., what you need to do is to load the calendar only when this variables comes `defined`.

So, you need

```
ng-if="uiConfig!==undefined"
```

if this variables defined then only your calendar will comes into picture.

Your div should look like this

```
 <div class="span8" ng-if="uiConfig!==undefined">
          <div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar1" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
  </div>
```

this will make sure to initialize when this variables has some values.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z9xu1p8y/)

Comment: I have tried your way and add the ng-if directive in my code. But this time the itself doesn't appear on the page. Only the white background renders in the page.
And now there is no error in the console. I have check my `uiConfig` is logging well in the console. Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

Also, the last error that I'm getting is `length undefined`.

Comment: @NitinGupta you have to wait for 5 seconds for it to appear

Comment: sorry I have waited more than 5 minutes to appear. But nothing happening. Can you please tell what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: @NitinGupta put your code in jsfiddle and share a link here

Comment: Hey, can you come on appear or hangouts please?
Because when I run it as an independent project it works fine.
But when I'm trying to add in existing project it behaves like above I described.

Comment: @NitinGupta you need to reproduce an issue in jsfiddle then only I can help